# cycling an array of images is stopped after the first cycle

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
var arr = $("#w01 > img").toArray(); // array created from images in a div
$('.btns .next').click(function(){
    var first = arr[0];
    arr.push(arr.shift(first)); //moves the first image at the bottom of the stack
    $(arr[0]).show(); //shows the next image
});
```

It works, but when the last image is reached, the process is stopped, instead of displaying the first image again, in an endless cycle !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine, but when you have showed all images and try to show the first image again, all the other images are already on top of it so showing it has no effect.

The `show` method only changes the visibility status of an element, it doesn't move the element to a place where it can be seen.

Hide the current image when you show a new one, that way there will only be one image visible at a time:

```
var arr = $("#w01 > img").toArray(); // array created from images in a div
$('.btns .next').click(function(){
    $(arr[0]).hide();
    arr.push(arr.shift()); //moves the first image at the bottom of the stack
    $(arr[0]).show(); //shows the next image
});
```

Note: The `shift` method doesn't use a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without any HTML or any suggestion about what it looks like. But I would presume it's because you're not hiding any of the previous images when you show the next - which means the images might be stacked on top of each other.

Try put:

```
$("#w01 > img").hide();
```

as the first line in the click handler and see what you get.